# deep convolutional network with masking, correct input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mask, masking

What would be optimal input shape for convolutional network with masking,

My input

```
X = (nO.samples, 750, 3)
```

3 stands for xyz, as my data is a chain of consecutive points in space, and each one has 3 features,

```
y = (nO.samples, 750)
```

each sample has length of 750, that is post padded value,  I used zero padding, and thus I want to mask those zeros, as they carry a lot of noise (I think)
yet:

```
input_shape = ( 748, 3)
model = Sequential(
[
    #Input(shape = input_shape ),
    Masking(mask_value= 0. ,input_shape=input_shape),
    Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation = tf.nn.relu),
```

then as anticipated i got error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_24 is incompatible with the layer: : expected 
             min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 748, 3]
```

Can I expand dimensions after masking ? if so, then which one to expand

would it be `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 1)`

or maybe `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, -1)`

resulting in `(samples, 1, 750, 3)  vs  (samples, 750, 3, 1)`

As expected conv2d layer won't accept masked input, without expanding dims, as it's 3 dim , not four,

```
[None,750, 3]
```

For 2dconv input it's   `[batch, in_height,in_width,in_channels]`

I think in_height should be set to one <right?>  as it's 1 row,

in_width would be 750, and in channels  => 3??
since each point in range (750) has 3 features stored in one array.

I haven't tried to  get network to learn that it's noise itself, since I assumed it would take a long time to train.

Does it make any sense?
Does anyone have any hint maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As error says Conv2D expects inputs of 4D `batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)`

Input shape should be something like this `(4, 28, 28, 3)`

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.,
                                  input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))

output = model(x)
```